# brightness not working (Ideapad)

Tags: lenovo, laptop, brightness, backlight, ideapad

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on an Ideapad 3. As per title I can't control the brightness in any way. Using the function keys to change it has the only effect of editing the "sys/class/backlight/ideapad/brightness" file but nothing changes on the screen. What I have tried so far is to install xbacklight, change the boot options to force the proprietary backlight module and also another couple of things I found online that I can't remember. I kown there are already a bunch of posts about brightness issues but no solution I found seems to work for me.
I'd appreciate any help and a little patience for a beginner